# Very Slow Framerates in Phoronix Tests

Tags: ati, graphics, 3d, opengl

I am trying to setup my 3D graphics card.

```
$ lspci -nn | grep VGA
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI RV770 [Radeon HD 4850] [1002:9442]
```

According to the [Radeon Driver open source driver page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RadeonDriver), my card is very well supported. I followed the instructions to set it up (very simple now that there is not a lot of mucking about in xorg.conf).

I checked to see the driver was installed properly:

```
$ dmesg | grep drm
[    3.542014] [drm] Initialized drm 1.1.0 20060810
[    3.613929] [drm] radeon defaulting to kernel modesetting.
[    3.613933] [drm] radeon kernel modesetting enabled.
[    3.627683] [drm] initializing kernel modesetting (RV770 0x1002:0x9442 0x1043:0x024E)
```

I also installed mesa-utils so I could make sure OpenGL was working properly with my card. Here is the relevant info from that (please let me know if you need something else to answer my question):

```
$ glxinfo | grep rend
direct rendering: Yes
OpenGL renderer string: Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 0x300)
    GL_NV_conditional_render, GL_AMD_draw_buffers_blend,
```

(Note: I have dual monitors, but, at this point, they are showing the same image as I have not yet set that up.)

However, when I install phoronix-test-suite and run lightsmark, I only get 1FPS and everything completely freezes during the soft shadow test. I'm not very experienced with graphics/graphics cards, etc, and was wondering if anybody could point me in the right direction.

If I put additional output (VERBOSE) for glxinfo, I get this...don't know if this helps debug at all.

```
$ LIBGL_DEBUG=verbose glxinfo
name of display: :0
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/tls/r600_dri.so
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/r600_dri.so
libGL error: failed to open drm device: Permission denied
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/tls/swrast_dri.so
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/swrast_dri.so
libGL: Can't open configuration file /etc/drirc: No such file or directory.
libGL: Can't open configuration file /home/jason/.drirc: No such file or directory.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Took me a bit, but I figured out what was going on. Steps to resolve...

```
sudo chmod 666 /dev/dri/card0
```

That solved the permission issue.

```
sudo apt-get install driconf
driconf
```

This solved the driconf warnings that I was receiving.

And, just for good measure...dual monitors...

```
xrandr --output DVI-0 --left-of DVI-1
xrandr --output DVI-1 --right-of DVI-0
```

Comment: Adding yourself to the `video` group (using `sudo gpasswd -a $USER video`) followed by a re-login should give he same (persistent) effect as `sudo chmod 666 ...` in this case.

Comment: @Lekensteyn - Ah...forgot to mention that. I did add myself to the video group. Didn't realize I had to relog, though, for that to work. I'll give that a shot. (I like that better than having to change internal permissions on my devices.) Thanks!